# Ubuntu 10.04 compatibility

Tags: system-installation, compatibility

Has anybody installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS(server edition) on newer laptops? I am trying to install on HP8570w but it fails to complete network configuration as it neither recognizes the ethernet nor the wlan card. Is it a compatibility issue with the PCI version?

Comment: Which wlan and Wifi devices does your laptop have ?

Comment: Why install a server edition on a laptop?  If you want a server edition, suggest use 12.04 or 14.04 which will give you the newer kernels that should support your networking requirements.

Comment: thanks for the reply.I want to use intel's 5300 card instead of 6300 card in my laptop. Does it mean this 10.04 kernel does not support the newer hardwares anymore? Could I do any modifications to make it work?

Answer (score -1):

The 10.04 kernel is linux 2.6.31, which was released on 9 September, 2009. It is very old and does not support newer hardware like your late-2012 HP 8570w laptop.

Comment: thanks. do you know exactly what is the bottleneck here so that I would try to modify the driver etc,.

Comment: The kernel does not support your hardware because the hardware was released several years after the kernel. Ubuntu 10.04 is over 4 years old now, is there a particular reason you want to install it instead of 12.04 or 14.04? There is no easy way for you to make it work - hypothetically you could compile and install a modern kernel, but it is more trouble than it is worth. If you really need 10.04, why not run it under a VM or LXC?

Comment: Thanks! I need to use a tool which is built to work perfectly on 10.04. In any other version I need to put in extra efforts to get the tool working. well I will check the other possibilities :)